Morphism between product types as a product of diagonal maps
I am trying to follow this post
https://ncatlab.org/toddtrimble/show/Notes+on+predicate+logic
and I got confused on this paragraph:

From this point of view, a morphism between product types is a product of diagonal maps. $$\Pi_{i\in [m]}g(m)\to \Pi_{m\in M}g(m)^{h^{-1}(m)} = \Pi_{n\in N} f(n)$$

I suppose the $f$ and $g$ are the maps $[n]\to S$ and $[m]\to S$ in the commutative triangle just above this block of LaTeX on the webpage. Are they just $T'$ and $T$ or is this my misunderstand?
I am quite confused why is the category of product types $(Fin/S)^{op}$. Where does the opposite come from? And may I please ask for an explanation of this sentence:

where for each single-sort factor $s = g(m)$ in the domain, there is a diagonal map $s^!:s\to s^{h^{-1}}(m)$ (If $h^{-1}(m)$ is empty, this diagonal map is actually a projection map $s\to 1$.) In this way, each morphism in $Prod(S)$ is a “generalized diagonal map”. Such generalized diagonal maps may be considered as operations between types which come “for free”.

I do not see where is a diagonl map. My understanding of a diagonal map is some map sending $x\mapsto (x,...,x)$. I do not discover anything here in this form.
May I please ask for what this paragraph is talking about? It might be the case that this is just a matter of notation and I did not find the correct correspondence. An answer with some examples will be particularly appreciated.

I agree that the notation in that section is inconsistent and confusing. I think the formula was meant to read as follows:
$$\prod_{i \in [m]} T(i) \to \left(\prod_{i \in [m]} T(i)^{h^{-1}(i)} = \prod_{j \in [n]} T'(j)\right)$$
As an example, let's fix our universe of sorts to be $S = \{a, b, c\}$ and consider the types
$$
\begin{align}
T &: [m = 4] \to S \\
T &= a \times b \times a \times c \\
T' &: [n = 3] \to S \\
T' &= a \times c \times a
\end{align}
$$
That is, $T(1) = a, T(2) = b$, etc.
The morphisms $T \to T'$ are terms of the form $\langle a_1, b_2, a_3, c_4 \rangle \mapsto \langle a_i, b_j, a_k \rangle$ for $i, k \in \{1, 3\}$ and $j \in \{2\}$; in general, we have to decide which projection of the input to use for each output component, in a way that respects the types. You should convince yourself that this is the same as a function $[n] \to [m]$ that makes the triangle commute, hence a morphism $T' \to T$ in $\mathbf{Fin}/S$; thus this category is equivalent to $(\mathbf{Fin}/S)^\mathrm{op}$.
Let us now focus on the morphism $$\begin{align}h &: T \to T' \\ h &= \langle a_1, b_2, a_3, c_4 \rangle \mapsto \langle a_1, c_4, a_1 \rangle\end{align}$$
Using the fact that the product is commutative up to isomorphism, we can rewrite this as
$$
h : a \times b \times a \times c \to (a^{\{1, 3\}} \times b^{\{\}} \times a^{\{\}} \times c^{\{2\}} = a \times c \times a)
$$
with the exponents given by $h^{-1}$ (e.g. $h^{-1}(1) = \{1, 3\}$).
Now that the codomain is in this form, we can rewrite $h$ as a product of diagonal maps as follows:
$$
h = (\lambda a. \langle a, a \rangle) \times (\lambda b. \langle \rangle) \times (\lambda a. \langle \rangle) \times (\lambda c. \langle c \rangle)
$$

Thanks! This is very helpful! However, I am still confused by why a morphism $T\to T'$ is a map $\langle a_1,b_2,a_3,c_4\rangle\mapsto \langle a_i,b_j,a_k\rangle$ where $i,k\in {1,3}$ and $j\in {2}$, rather than any $a_i,a_k\in a$ and $b_j\in b$, where $a,b$ are actual types with the names $a,b$?

I don't know what you mean by that. $a$ and $b$ aren't sets.

So is that true that a morphism $T\to T’$ is just by definition a map of tuples such that a tuple is reassembled as you wrote above? To me, it seems like despite the fact that $a,b,c$ are not, sets, they are considered as names of sets since we are taking the product of them.

Keep in mind that we are describing the free category with products on $a, b, c$: we are taking $a, b, c$ as our basic objects and freely adding categorical products between them (which come with projections and diagonal maps).
